# Forcing evaluation first in a pattern match?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching, ghci

I would like to re-run a function back on a pattern after that same function has been evaluated on parameters inside a Data constructor being passed to the function. For example

```
func (Plus a b) = func (Plus (func a) (func b))
```

Note that `a` and `func a` are of the same type. When I try to call something like this, the program gets hung up, and I think what's happening is the pattern is getting indefinitely matched against itself before evaluating the inner `(func a)` and `(func b)`, which would otherwise match it to a different pattern. I have tried using something like

```
func (Plus a b) = func (Plus newa newb)
    where newa = func a
          newb = func b
```

to try and force the evaluation of `func a` and `func b` first, but this does not work. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense. `func (Plus a b) = func (Plus _ _)` will *always* hang, no matter what you do. It doesn't really have anything to do with evaluation order. You should probably include in the question some more detail as to what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: As in: what do you want `func` to do? If you can describe that in english it'll be easier for people to answet the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do get into a loop where you match `Plus` over and over, but what do you expect?

```
func (Plus a b)
   = func (Plus (func a) (func b))
   = func (Plus (func (func a)) (func (func b)))
   = func (Plus (func (func (func a))) (func (func (func b))))
```

The problem is that you are essentially saying, "to evaluate `func` on a `Plus` constructor, evaluate `func` on a `Plus` constructor".

What does the rest of `func` look like?  Your approach could, in principle, work if the whole definition were something like:

```
func (Plus (Lit n) (Lit m)) = Lit (n + m)
func (Plus a b) = func (Plus (func a) (func b))
```

Here if `func a` and `func b` eventually reduce to `Lit`, then the first pattern will match and the call will terminate.  But I would hesitate to write a function this way, because how do you know that repeatedly calling `func` on an argument will eventually converge to `Lit`?  There will probably be a case where it won't.

---

I suspect you are writing a symbolic evaluator.  The better way to do this is to come up with a *normal form* for expressions, and then have your reducer reduce to the normal form.  A normal form is a unique representation that you can always reduce an expression to. It sometimes takes some cunning to come up with a good normal form.  But let's say your expression type were:

```
data Expr = Lit Int | Var String | Plus Expr Expr
```

For this, an example normal form might be:

```
data ExprNF = ExprNF Int [String]
```

which represents a constant plus a sum of variables in sorted order (keep it sorted so that equivalent expressions always compare equal).  So if your expression were

```
1 + (x + 2) + (3 + 6) + (x + (y + x))
```

It would become the normal form:

```
ExprNF 10 ["x","x","x","y"]
```

Your reducer `func :: Expr -> ExprNF` computes the normal form recursively, and there is no need to repeatedly call it in hopes of convergence.

```
func :: Expr -> ExprNF
func (Lit n) = ExprNF n []
func (Var s) = ExprNF 0 [s]
func (Plus a b) = case (func a, func b) of
    (ExprNF n vs, ExprNF n' vs') -> ExprNF (n + n') (sort (vs ++ vs'))
```

We never have to reduce any node in the tree more than once, because we get a normal form right away.

Comment: Your intuition as to my motivation is very close, and I appreciate the time you took to write out your very detailed answer. Thank you!